# Give only Read access to Private GitHub Repo

Tags: github

Is it possible to just show someone my repo so they can code review it but only have read access to it?  Like can I just share my private repo link to someone kinda like the unlisted items in Google drive that as long as they know the url to get to the private repo they can read and look at the files in the browser through GitHub?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-outside-collaborators-to-repositories-in-your-organization/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an organizational Github account this granularity might not be available.

Collaborators in a personal private repository have :

> Push to (write), pull from (read), and fork (copy) the repository.
>
> Apply labels and milestones
>
> Open, close, re-open, and assign issues.
>
> Edit and delete comments on commits, pull requests, and issues
>
> Merge and close pull requests
>
> Send pull requests from forks of the repository
>
> Create and edit Wikis
>
> Create and edit Releases
>
> Remove themselves as collaborators on the repository

With Organizational private repositories there is the option to designate "Read Access Teams" for code review without write privileges.

https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-an-organization-repository/

https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/